# How prove this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$ divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Show that this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$$
is divergent.
**My try**: since
$$u_{n}=\dfrac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n},\Longrightarrow \dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\dfrac{e^{n+1}\cdot(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\dfrac{n^n}{e^n\cdot n!}=\dfrac{e}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}=1$$
so this limit is $1$, therefore I can't prove it by using the Ratio test.

**From sos440 suggestion**: by using Stirling's approximation, we have
$$\dfrac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n}\approx \sqrt{2n\pi}\to\infty.$$

Maybe this problem requires other methods.

Comment: If you are allowed to use Stirling's formula, then it is straightforward.

Comment: The terms themselves do not approach $0$. Try to show that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n \nearrow e$, the succesive quotients are always greater or equal to $1$. This means that $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$ for each $n$. In particular $a_n\geqslant a_1$ for each $n$.  Since $a_1$ is positive, the sequence doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: Hello,then? Thank you

Comment: @chinamath Does $a_n\to 0$?

Comment: But $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Using Logarithmic test..

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}nlog\dfrac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}-n+n^2log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})$$
expand $log(1+\frac{1}{n})$ into its series  and u get limit as -1/2 < 1
So by log test series diverge